# Getting error while redeploying camel proxy on tomcat 7

Tags: spring, proxy, tomcat7, cxf, apache-camel

I have created a proxy service using apache camel that i have deployed on Tomcat.
So when i start tomcat everything works fine and i can see the proxy service which i have hosted on port 9080.

I have used the property **WatchedResource** in context.xml inside the tomcat directory/conf folder.
So here i am monitoring changes done to my camel-config.xml. I f any changes happen in camel-config.xml, then tomcat tries to redeploy the above service. But while tomcat tries to auto redeploy the service it throws error as :

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not add cxf jetty handler for url http:/
/localhost:9080/camel-example-cxf-proxy/webservices/versionAdapter to Jetty server, as the path /camel-example-cxf-proxy/
webservices/versionAdapter is still in use.
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1364)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:122)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:327)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMult
icaster.java:96)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:3
34)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:
948)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java
:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java
:93)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:157)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.example.cxf.proxy.MyMain.init(MyMain.java:31)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3920)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1357)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1451)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:296)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not add cxf jetty handler for url http://localhost:9080/camel-example-
cxf-proxy/webservices/versionAdapter to Jetty server, as the path /camel-example-cxf-proxy/webservices/versionAdapter is
 still in use.
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.checkRegistedContext(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:297
)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:320)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:49)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBindingFactory.java:95)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.addListener(SoapBindingFactory.java:895)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:123)
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer.doStart(CxfConsumer.java:271)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:2158)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:2452)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:2388)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:2318)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:2091)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1951)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1777)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1745)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:254)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:120)
        ... 28 more
```

How to solve this problem. Looking forward to your solutions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of camel are you using? It look like you don't shutdown the camel context rightly.

Comment: i am using camel 2.14